# How to maintain a specific time duration between calling two functions in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to create a code that calls one Function say `toStart()` and then calls another function `toStop()` exactly after two seconds the first function has been called until I push another button `nowComplete`. I have learned a function `setInterval()` but it only calls the function `toStop()` after every two seconds the page has loaded, it doesn't depend on the time when the function `toStart()` has started. How can I get rid of this?

```
<button type="button" onclick="nowend">Now Complete</button>
<script>
function toStart(){
  //do something here
  setInterval(toStop,2000);
}

function toStop(){
  //do Something here
}
function nowend(){
//Stop both the functions here to work
}
```

Comment: Could you explain more what the button should do? Should the sequence _toStart, 2 s, toStop_ be executed once, and the button needs to be pressed in the 2 s window to avoid _toStop_ to be called? Is _toStop_ doing something in a loop which should be interrupted by the button?

Comment: Yes, this is the exact thing you have understood. The button is to be pressed between the 2s time, either from `toStart` to `toStop` or from `toStop` to `toStart`. The function `toStop` may interrupt something in the window. For example, consider a program a light bulb is being illuminated by this two functions. By pressing the button `nowend()` the user has to stop any of the function to go the next one. If the `toStart` function has just been called and then the button is pressed, the `toStop` function won't be called anymore and the bulb shall remain illuminated forever.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:
setTimeout() is the counterpart to setInterval().

```
function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

sleep(2000)
  .then(() => toStart())
  .then(() => sleep(2000))
  .then(() => toStop())
```

With this function you are a bit more flexible.

If you want to read more about different methods you could achieve you're goal: https://www.sitepoint.com/delay-sleep-pause-wait/

Answer (score 1):

The below code will log 'started' in the console and then 'stopped' after 2 seconds. If 'nowComplete' button is pressed before 2 seconds, the timeout is cancelled and 'stopped' will not be logged. Refer [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout) and [clearTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/clearTimeout)

```
<button type="button" onclick="nowEnd">Now Complete</button>
<script>
let timeoutId;

function toStart(){
  console.log('started');
  timeoutId = setTimeout(toStop, 2000);
}

function toStop(){
  console.log('stopped');
}
function nowEnd(){
  clearTimeout(timeoutId);
}

toStart();
</script>
```